# How can I carry my compound bow in a backpack without showing any parts of it?

Tags: united-states, archery, bows

I’m looking for a bag to help carry my bow. Not that hard in huge forums to find some good suggestions but the think is I’m looking specifically to carry a compound bow without **exposing any of the parts of that bow.**

I live in NY and it’s **illegal to carry bows without them being out of sight** so slings and packs that strap the bow to it are no good for me. I’m not looking to take the thing hunting; just to range and back.

Comment: Just want to warn you to be careful. Depending on your county, some local law enforcement in New York state bully weapon owners by arresting them even when they are following all of the laws. They tend to make silly claims such as "You are disturbing the peace, because people can tell that you have a weapon. It doesn't matter that you are following all the laws." If you don't want to be bullied by law enforcement, you can do a Google search for how different counties' law enforcement react to weapons. Hopefully you are in a good one. Just be careful!

Comment: Please add bow size to your question. A picture or reference link would even be better.

Comment: New related question [Are there Takedown Compound Bows?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20560/are-there-takedown-compound-bows)

Comment: I shot competitive archery for years across the country, just use a soft or hard case similar to a gun case,  these are standard products, the nice one are made by pelican and have lifetime warranties. Never had a problem even on Columbia Campus in NYC! There are ones with wheels that look like suitcases if you are hyper paranoid

Answer (score 9):

If you're simply looking for a bag to transport your bow in, then go shopping for a **[compound bow bag](https://www.cabelas.ca/category/cases/1298)**. There is a large selection of bags available.

[image: Bow Case]

If you're specifically looking to invest in a backpack that you can strap your bow too, then you can look for a compatible [**bow cover**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B074CR75ND) to conceal your bow.

[image: Bow Cover or Sleeve]

If you just want to get to the range without getting fined or arrested, perhaps it is sufficient to **wrap your bow** in a sheet or put it in a black garbage bag and stuff it into the top biggest backpack you have, or strap it to the outside.

I'm sure the guys at the range who have to abide by the same laws as you will have plenty of suggestions. It's always best to ask the locals when it comes to local laws.

Comment: In OP's region, assuming they are not in or near New York City, it is common for most people to own their own vehicle and transport their guns and bows in their vehicle. Most people do not walk around with them because of how strict the laws are, and the police in some counties of New York state will arrest people even if they are following all the laws (they tend to claim that you're causing a disturbance, or something similar). For that reason, those at the range might not be able to help. Either OP lives in a reasonable county, or they are bravely tempting bully police.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options,

- A soft case for your bow, put the bow inside the case and strap the whole thing to your backpack.
- A bow case with backpack straps.
- A bow case with a padded shoulder sling (these are more common than ones with backpack straps).

Answer (score 0):

> How can I carry my compound bow in a backpack without showing any parts of it?

You can't

There are a couple of good answers suggesting alternatives, and a comment or two about hazards, of these choices.

But you can purchase a TV Moving Box, online or from the local moving company and truck rental place.  They are designed for flat screen TV's  These are available in different sizes starting at about $25.  Put your bow in it and carry it like it is a flat screen TV.

Alternately: you can purchase a [takedown bow](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20560/are-there-takedown-compound-bows) that would be easier to pack, but I don't think that is what you are looking for.

Alternately: You can get an Army Duffle Bag, with shoulder straps, it is effectively a large backpack. It should hold your bow, arrows and other gear, while functioning as backpack. Amazon sells them [new for about $50](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N170CCX) with several surplus stores selling used ones for about $20

Comment: You're not going to get a takedown compound worth owning. They're effectively extinct.